# How do you add to default typings in a package

Tags: typescript

I'm using express and I changed stuff inside of it so that instead of doing

`res.send(200).json("something")`

I can instead do:

`res.ok("something")`

BUT, I'm getting an error in my ide saying that 'ok' does not exist in type Response. I installed express typings and guessing that I need to add ok to the typings? But I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

```
function codes(): any {
  return (req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
    function init(cb:any) {
      Object.keys(status).forEach(i => {
        Object.defineProperty(res, status[i].method, {
          enumerable: true,
          configurable: true,
          value: function(data: any, msg: string) {
            try {
              res.statusMessage = msg;
              res.status(i).json(data || null)
            } catch(err) {
              next(err)
            }
          },
          writable: true
        });
      })
      if (req.query) {
        var query = "";
        for (let q in req.query) {
          query += `${q}: ${req.query[q]}, `;
        }
        var query = query.slice(0, -1);
        Object.defineProperty(req, "stringQ", {
          enumerable: true,
          configurable: true,
          value: query
        })
      }
      cb();
    }
    init(() => {
      next();
    })
  }
}
```

I have the router use this function at the start by doing:
`router.use(codes());` The Object `status` that you don't see declared here is just an object that has the status codes and messages.

Comment: How did you 'change stuff inside'?

Comment: hi I added how I changed the stuff inside

Comment: Did you change files in `node_modules` or did you create a fork?

Comment: I didn't do either. I just added this to the router after it was declared.

Comment: you need to merge `Response` declarations by augmenting the `express` module, see handbook section on [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation). Something along the lines of: `import type { Response } from "express";

declare module "express" {
    interface Response {
        OK() : boolean;
    }
}`